# How to make ExoPlayer recognize a source type by its URL?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I started using ExoPlayer recently in my Android application, but the problem that I faced was that ExoPlayer doesn't recognize automatically the source type by a stream URL.

Is there any solution so I can pass a URL and ExoPlayer defines automatically how to play it ( As a video or an HLS stream)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri, String overrideExtension) {
    int type = TextUtils.isEmpty(overrideExtension) ? Util.inferContentType(uri)
    : Util.inferContentType("." + overrideExtension);
    switch (type) {
      case C.TYPE_SS:
          return new SsMediaSource(uri, buildDataSourceFactory(false),
              new DefaultSsChunkSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory), mainHandler, eventLogger);
      case C.TYPE_DASH:
          return new DashMediaSource(uri, buildDataSourceFactory(false),
              new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory), mainHandler, eventLogger);
      case C.TYPE_HLS:
          return new HlsMediaSource(uri, mediaDataSourceFactory, mainHandler, eventLogger);
      case C.TYPE_OTHER:
          return new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, mediaDataSourceFactory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(),
              mainHandler, eventLogger);
      default: {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported type: " + type);
    }
}
```

}

Source: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/PlayerActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

You can learn source type like this:

For `Kotlin`:

```kotlin
private fun checkMediaType() {
        val type = when(Util.inferContentType(URL.toUri())){
            C.CONTENT_TYPE_HLS -> {
                println("Type HLS")
            }
            C.CONTENT_TYPE_DASH -> {
                println("Type DAS")
            }
            C.CONTENT_TYPE_OTHER -> {
                println("Type OTHER")
            }
            C.CONTENT_TYPE_SS -> {
                println("Type SS")
            }
            C.CONTENT_TYPE_RTSP -> {
                println("Type RTSP")
            }
            else -> {}
        }
        return type
    }
```